# Creating a SSH screen through PHP with phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, gnu-screen, phpseclib

I have a PHP script in which I am trying to create a screen on my ssh server with the PHP SSH library phpseclib. This is the function that I am using to try to create the screen:

```
 function startscreen($ssh, $user)
 {
      $ssh->exec("screen -S ".$user);
 }
```

And this is how I am calling the function:

```
startscreen($ssh, $user);
```

I know I can create screens this way, but it will not work remotely with php.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all familiar with screen but... reading about it on wikipedia makes me wonder if it even makes sense to do it via exec(). Like doing exec('vim') doesn't make a ton of sense because vim expects user input after that and exec() doesn't really provide a mechanism for user input to be provided.

Maybe the [read() / write()](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#interactive) commands would work better for you? Maybe you'd need to do nohup and & to send it to the background?